# let $ (X, d) $ be a metric space and $ {x_n} $ a sequence in $ X $ convergent in $ x \in X $

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

sea $(X,d)$ un espacio métrico y ${x_n}$ una sucesión en $X$ convergente en $x \in X$ entonces para algún $\alpha \in X$, la sucesión $d(x_n, \alpha)$ converge a $d(x, \alpha)$

> Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $\{x_n\}$ a sequence in $X$ converging to $x\in X$; then for any $\alpha\in X$, the sequence $d(x_n,\alpha)$ converges to $d(x,\alpha)$.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried using the triangle inequality in various ways?

Comment: Pista: $d(-,\alpha):X\to \mathbb R$ es continua, misma que se demuestra con la desigualdad triangular.

Answer (score 1):

Given $\{x_n\}$ converges to $x$,
we know $\forall$ $\epsilon>0$, $\exists N$ such that if $n>N$, $d(x_n,x)<\epsilon$

By triangle inequality, $$d(x_n,a)≤d(x_n,x)+d(x,a)$$ and$$d(x,a)≤d(x_n,x)+d(x_n,a)$$

Since $d(x_n,x)<\epsilon$, $$d(x_n,a)-d(x,a)<\epsilon$$ and $$d(x,a)-d(x_n,a)<\epsilon$$ Hence,
$$|d(x_n,a)-d(x,a)|<\epsilon$$

Comment: The value of $\;d(x_n,a)-d(x,a)\;$ can be negative. It must be proved that $\;d(x,a)-d(x_n,a)<\epsilon\;$ also holds, so $\;|d(x_n,a)-d(x,a)|<\epsilon.$ This can be done with the same technique you just used.

Comment: @gpassante thank you for pointing that out, have edited the answer to take that into account!